# Can we Export data from Azure Catalog to CSV? including tags?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I have data(tables) in an Azure Catalog with some user-defined tags in it, now I want to import data in CSV including tags as a column

Answer (score 0):

> Can we Export data from Azure Catalog to CSV?

It seems that this feature is currently not supported in Azure Data Catalog.

Until now, in the official feature suggestion for Microsoft Azure forum, there has been a such suggestion with similar issue exist in it: [Export search results to CSV](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/906052-data-catalog/suggestions/32317552-export-search-results-to-csv). You can comment and vote it there.